# Network through USB?

Tags: networking, usb

My Macbook is lacking an Ethernet port, but can network through USB. If I set up the Raspberry Pi as an internet router, can it route traffic through USB to my Macbook?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes, but direct USB-USB communication is not possible. What you'll want is a USB-Ethernet adapter for your Macbook. After you get one of those, networking should be straightforward.